# Como criar pai e filhos dando duas ou mais colunas como agrupamento num SELECT qualquer de forma eficiente?

Tags: mysql

Vamos supor que tenho dados similares ao abaixo, mas a tabela completa tem: autoincremento, valores de medições, datas, chaves estrangeiras, textos descritivos. No exemplo que criei, tem apenas autoincremento, um valor, uma data e duas chaves estrangeiras que representam um equipamento e um cliente. O mesmo equipamento poderá ter mais de um cliente e um cliente poderá ter mais de um equipamento.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `teste_stackoverflow`;
CREATE TABLE `teste_stackoverflow`  (
  `auto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(255),
  `chave_estrangeira_1` INT,
  `chave_estrangeira_2` INT,
  `valor` DOUBLE,
  `data` DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (`auto`) USING BTREE
);
INSERT INTO `teste_stackoverflow` VALUES (1, 'Material 1', 1, 1, 1.300, '2019-04-02 12:04:40');
INSERT INTO `teste_stackoverflow` VALUES (2, 'Material 2', 1, 2, 1.500, '2019-04-02 12:05:59');
INSERT INTO `teste_stackoverflow` VALUES (3, 'Material 3', 2, 1, 1.400, '2020-04-02 12:06:34');
INSERT INTO `teste_stackoverflow` VALUES (4, 'Material 4', 1, 1, 1.700, '2020-04-02 12:06:52');
INSERT INTO `teste_stackoverflow` VALUES (5, 'Material 5', 1, 2, 1.800, '2020-04-02 12:07:22');
```

Tendo esse cenário, eu quero criar um 'histórico' baseado nessas duas chaves estrangeiras. Para cada linha, apontar o id ou `auto` dos anteriores como pai. Eu consegui algo com a consulta

```
    WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT      
        auto, auto as historico_auto, descricao, chave_estrangeira_1, chave_estrangeira_2, valor, data
    FROM teste_stackoverflow
    ORDER BY data DESC
)
    SELECT
        T1.auto, CTE.historico_auto, T1.descricao,T1.chave_estrangeira_1,T1.chave_estrangeira_2, T1.valor, T1.data
    FROM teste_stackoverflow AS T1
        INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.chave_estrangeira_1 = T1.chave_estrangeira_1 AND CTE.chave_estrangeira_2 = T1.chave_estrangeira_2
    WHERE T1.Auto <= CTE.historico_auto
    ORDER BY historico_auto, auto;
```

Que trouxe, do jeito que eu queria:

```
+------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
| auto | historico_auto | descricao  | chave_estrangeira_1 | chave_estrangeira_2 | valor | data                |
+------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 |              1 | Material 1 |                   1 |                   1 | 1.300 | 2019-04-02 12:04:40 |
|    2 |              2 | Material 2 |                   1 |                   2 | 1.500 | 2019-04-02 12:05:59 |
|    3 |              3 | Material 3 |                   2 |                   1 | 1.400 | 2020-04-02 12:06:34 |
|    1 |              4 | Material 1 |                   1 |                   1 | 1.300 | 2019-04-02 12:04:40 |
|    4 |              4 | Material 4 |                   1 |                   1 | 1.700 | 2020-04-02 12:06:52 |
|    2 |              5 | Material 2 |                   1 |                   2 | 1.500 | 2019-04-02 12:05:59 |
|    5 |              5 | Material 5 |                   1 |                   2 | 1.800 | 2020-04-02 12:07:22 |
+------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+
```

Com a tabela real, com os vários 'valores', 'datas', textos e outras informações, em uns 86 mil registros, essa consulta não conclui. Fica vários minutos rodando sem trazer qualquer resultado, mesmo quando uso apenas as colunas necessárias para a lógica, como no exemplo criado e citado.
Há alguma forma mais eficiente de abordar esse problema?